# Jenkins plugin to run multiple source code management after build steps

Tags: plugins, jenkins

i am using jenkins for automation builds.
my issue is i want to download sources from svn and run the build steps and after running the builds steps once again i want to take latest sources from svn.
is there any plugin for it where my requirement satisfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting up two jobs (A and B) with a shared workspace (job > configure > Advanced Project Options ; click button *Advanced...*). check custom workspace and define a location). Once job A is finished it triggers job B and job B then performs a svn update plus whatever else you need. In order to avoid parallel execution of A and B, check *Block build when upstream project is building* and *Block build when downstream project is building*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a plugin, but you can always run manual SVN commands as part of the build step

- Add a new build step to "Execute shell" (if on Linux) or "Execute Windows batch command" 
  (if on Windows).
- Inside, write SVN commands, depending on your OS, for example:
- `svn up checkout_folder`, note that path will be relative to Jenkin's workspace